# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {840177AB-C69A-463C-8FAF-8137489EF565}

Tags: asp.net, .net, electron, window, electron-builder

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {840177AB-C69A-463C-8FAF-8137489EF565} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`

I am getting this error while running code on Windows 10, the same code is working fine on my Windows 7 system.

Comment: btw this issue coming while i'm printing card with zebra printer in windows 10

Comment: here is the image link: https://wystap.s3.amazonaws.com/Screenshot+(107).png